# Magento Product images and name not showing for custom Block

Tags: php, magento

I have the following code to show the most viewed products in my store. The problem is the products are showing without any image(place holder image is showing) and name. If I disable the Flat category and Product from back end the images and products names are showing, but I am not allowed to disable it. I don't know what I am missing please help.

```
<?php
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Viewed extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            ->addViewsCount();
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

        $products->setPageSize(5)->setCurPage(1);
        $this->setProductCollection($products);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you re-index the data? Try after that adding `->joinAttribute('image', 'catalog_product/image', 'entity_id', null, 'left')` instead.

Comment: please show phtml file code

Comment: Yes i have done it but didn't help. You want me to replace ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','price','small_image')) with ->joinAttribute('image', 'catalog_product/image', 'entity_id', null, 'left') ??..